# Jquery bookblock plugin jump to last page on startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using BookBlock jquery plugin .[View Here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/03/bookblock-a-content-flip-plugin/)

And I want to implement demo4.html like feature in my web application!
I directly want to move to the last page when that page is loaded.
Is this possible?.
It looks like this:

`

```
            <div id="bb-bookblock" class="bb-bookblock">
                <div class="bb-item">
                    <div class="bb-custom-side">
                        First Page
                    </div>
                    <div class="bb-custom-side">
                        Hello
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="bb-item">
                    <div class="bb-custom-side">
                        last page
                    </div>
                    <div class="bb-custom-side">
                        Bye
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>`
```

Currently the first page is first div.
I want to view the last div directly onLoad..Is their any function ?
I saw the jquery file but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/03/bookblock-a-content-flip-plugin/), you should use

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( ‘#bb-bookblock’ ).bookblock( ‘last’ );
});
```